# Why Spring Mvc application with Hibernate throw an error: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I followed the tutorial on the following link:[Tutorial Spring MVC](https://o7planning.org/10601/spring-mvc-form-handling-and-hibernate), and I used Ubunto, MySQL and Eclipse, but at runtime I received an error, below the trace of the error:

> Root Cause
>
> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
> Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire
> JDBC Connection
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:541)
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
> org.o7planning.springmvcforms.controller.MyController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$32fb6e31.applicantList()
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

And below the config properties file:

```
# DataSource

ds.database-driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_databse?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
ds.username=root
ds.password=mypassword


# Hibernate Config

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
current_session_context_class=thread
```

And below the function used for configuration of Hibernate:

```
 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
 public DataSource getDataSource() {
     DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

     dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver"));
     dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url"));
     dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("ds.username"));
     dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password"));
     
     return dataSource;
 }
```

And here is the function to create session Factory object:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)throws Exception  {    
    Properties properties = new Properties();      
         // See: ds-hibernate-cfg.properties
     properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
     properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
     properties.put("current_session_context_class", env.getProperty("current_session_context_class"));
     
     LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
     factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.o7planning.springmvcforms.entity" });       
     
     factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
     factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
     factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
     //
    SessionFactory sf = factoryBean.getObject();
    return sf;
}
```

What is the source of this error?

Comment: You need to look at the full exception stracktrace, and possibly at log messages before this one.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, thanks for replying, the post was updated with the full trace for the exception.

Comment: You are unable to obtain a JDBC connection.  The error is clear.  It could mean that you are A) Have a problem with your connection URL/Settings, B) You have some firewall, C) Maybe incorrect port?
 
Something is off with your connection settings.  Maybe paste those and someone could help.

Comment: @SMA, thanks for answer,the post was updated as expected. and answering to your suggestion, i was able to connect with the same paramters with "Mysql Workbensh" but it was not possible from eclipse environment. Knowing that the environment is under Linux Ubunto, any idea ? thanks

Comment: This is unlikely to be the full exception stacktrace. Generally, this exception has one or more "caused by" exception causes chained to it. Check your logs. Also, is your database really called `my_databse` (and not - typo fixed - `my_database`)?

Comment: @Mark Rottevell, can you tell me where is located the log file ? thanks

Comment: That depends on your logging configuration and application deployment.

Comment: @Mark Rottevell : Currently I have not added the log functionality, I use eclipse debugging. the code is that of the tutorial indicated above, but it is on Linux and not windows which can bring me back if a configuration must be made such as for example the unlocking of eclipse or tomcat to connect to the port 3306

Comment: Does one have an idea about this connection issue ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, for those who encounter the same problem.
Indeed the version of **Mysql** is **8.0.28**,for this reason it is necessary to use the version **8.0.11** of **Mysql** connector and to use the configuration of driver under the bellow format:

```
ds.database-d=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

instead of

```
ds.database-d=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Hoping it can help